# New method for exoplanet detection based on iridescence?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, planet, exoplanet

Could it be possible to detect exoplanets that have an abundance of [iridescent minerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) by analyzing their star's spectra over time as the angle in observation would lead to changes in absorbed wavelengths?

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I edited in a link, hope that is ok for you. I am sure you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets

Comment: Spectral lines are helpful in determining the chemical composition of exoplanets.

Comment: It sounds like a very challenging observation. I'd guess it is impossible.  If it is possible, iridecencte is rare enough to make it of limited value.

Comment: I've just asked a complementary question in Space SE: [Has iridescence ever been observed on any solar system body besides Earth? Or at least from a sample from one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54588/12102)

Comment: and also [Has opalescence ever been observed on any solar system body besides Earth? Or at least from a sample from one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54589/12102)